# why does document in $(document).ready(); not need quotations like the other elements you manipulate in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to coding and want to have a strong foundation of understanding

Ex:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div').fadeOut('fast'); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `document` is a variable representing an object in the DOM, and not a string. Passing things like `'div'`, or `'.my-class'` are selectors that you're passing to Sizzle (the Selector Engine used in jQuery).

jQuery can also accept DOM objects as an argument, and will generate a jQuery collection around them.

For example, the following is also valid:

```
$(window).resize();
```

And you could even do something like this (although this is largely academic, quite why you'd do this in the wild, I don't know):

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
    $myDiv = $(myDiv);
```

Answer (score 3):

Because `document` is a pre-defined global variable that is a reference to the current document object. Whereas when you're using a string with `$()`, you're giving it a CSS selector to go find matching elements within the document.

Answer (score 0):

document isn't an element in the DOM. It is the property of window. And JavaScript has an object for it in scope ready to be used. So this selector:

```
$(document)
```

is referencing that object, wrapping it in the jQuery function to create a jQuery object based on the original object. This same thing happens a lot. For example, you can do this:

```
var someElement = document.getElementById('someId');
```

Now someElement is an object. (Which coincidentally happens to refer to an HTML element in the DOM, but that's not important.) And it can be wrapped as a jQuery object:

```
$(someElement)
```

Comment: Actually, it's not the DOM - it's a property of `window`... You might also be better off upvoting the answers already posted, rather than duplicating them.

Comment: Even after the edit, your opening gambit is still wrong. `document` is an element in the DOM...